# behaviour outside the radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $\sum a_nz^n$ have radius of convergence $R$.  For $|z|>R$, is it true that the partial sums $S_N(z)=\sum_{n=0}^Na_nz^n$ diverge to infinity, i.e. is $\liminf |S_N(z)|=\infty$?  (In other words, does $S_N(z)$ converge to $\infty$ on the Riemann Sphere?)

Comment: The series diverges for $|z| > R$, yes.  This is equivalent to saying the sequence of partial sums diverges.

Comment: @tylerc0816 this doesn't address my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, the partial sum need not diverge to $\infty$. A counterexample is

$$a_n = \begin{cases}-1, & n \equiv 2\pmod 3\\+1, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The radius of convergence of $\displaystyle\quad\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n\quad$ is $1$ and yet:

$$S_{3k+2}(\varphi) = 0,\;\;\text{ for any } k \in \mathbb{N} \quad\implies\quad \liminf_{N\to\infty}\;\left|S_N(\varphi)\right|= 0$$

where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary for the series to diverge to infinity. Take, for example, $a_n=1$ for all $n$, and $z=-2$: then, $$\sum_{n=0}^N(-2)^n=\frac{1-(-2)^{N+1}}{3},$$ which oscillates between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: I'm talking about $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere, so this is not a counterexample.